# Why 64 times bit shift doesn't give me 0?

Tags: php, 64-bit, bit-shift

I'm reading `php_architects.zend.php_.5.certification.study.guide.2006` and want to play with bit shifts. I have Ubuntu 64bit. And here is my code:

```
$x = 1;
echo ($x << 64) . "\n";
echo $x * pow(2, 64) . "\n";
```

The output of this script is:

```
1
1.844674407371E+19
```

The second result is float due to type conversion, it's clear. But for first one I would expect 0 value.

Why I'm getting 1 instead of 0?

**UPD**
Made one more test:

```
echo ($x << 67) . "\n";
```

Gives:
8
Looks like cycling, but I would expect bit removal.

Answer (score 0):

In plain english you are moving the '1's to the left.

So `$x` is `0001` and `$x << 1` is `0010`. When you do this 64 times you turn were you started `0001`.

You are just moving the bits, never removing, so you will never get zero.

More info at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Well, the manual page you linked says the opposite: bit shifts aren't cyclic. Exact words: "Bits shifted off either end are discarded". So actual behaviour is different.
I think it might be related to running the script on 32-bit system... Just tested. Nope, 1 << 32 still gives 1 on 64-bit windows.

Comment: "shift" => digits are discarded VS. "roll" => bits are rolled back in the other side (there is no "roll" in PHP, but the operation is available in assembler). btw, fastest way to "null" a value is to XOR it with itself.